# Draw CNN model in latex

Tags: latex, conv-neural-network

please
Is there a way that I can draw a simple CNN architecture in LaTeX if I know that my model has: four convolutions, three blocks (convolution + BN + RELU + dropout), and then pooling after each layer.Then lastly a normal convolution Conv2d.
?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an interesting Python library: [PlotNeuralNet](https://github.com/HarisIqbal88/PlotNeuralNet)

You can directly produce LaTex code for drawing your CNN in Python. It seems like plotting directly fromt a Keras/TF model is not supported, but you can enter the model architecture and save a lot of Tikz headache ;)